# Google Chrome sync not working after I've removed work account from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I've been facing a weird issue which I'm yet to find whether it happened to other people too.

I've been using two different Microsoft accounts in my Windows 10 OS for the last couple of years without any issues. One is my personal and the other is work account. Both Windows and Google Chrome browser have been syncing across different devices. I have one other desktop in which I only use my personal Microsoft account in Windows and use the same Google account with the Chrome browser. Also I use the same Google account with my iOS Chrome browser.

Everything has been smooth until today when I've removed my work account from Windows. The problem only seems to be with the Chrome browser. Because I can see Windows settings are still being synced ok. After I've removed the work account Chrome failed to stay signed in with my Google account everytime I restarted it. Meaning when I close the Chrome browser and start it again:

- I'm signed out
- Open tabs from previous session are not being reloaded
- Syncing is turned off

I've tried the solution suggested here, but it didn't work for me:
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/93pop3/sync_is_paused_chrome_wont_stay_logged_into/

I've reset sync, signed out, signed back in, deleted browser cache, unistalled and re-installed Chrome, tried to re-sync with Windows defender turned off. But nothing worked.

Any clues on how I may be able to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

- Windows 10 Pro 1809 Build 17763.557
- Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: When uninstalling Chrome, did you use "Also delete your browsing data"? After uninstalling Chrome, you should also search on the entire computer and delete any folders containing "Chrome" or "Google".

Comment: No I didn't use that option. And I've also not searched for and deleted folders containing "Chrome" or "Google" after uninstalling. Let me try that..

Comment: @harrymc Yep that fixed it. Thanks a lot mate! Please post your tip as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, some traces of your work profile are still causing trouble.

To completely uninstall Chrome, specify "Also delete your browsing data"
during the uninstall, to completely erase profiles and browsing history.

After uninstalling Chrome, you should also search on the entire computer
and delete any folders containing the string "Chrome" or "Google".